# How to find same string in consecutive lines and then print all lines that consecutively contain them

Tags: logging, awk

I have a ping logfile with format

```
2021/02/15 14:22:27 : Reply[1] from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=31.9 ms TTL=244 jitter=0.00 ms
2021/02/15 14:22:27 : Reply[2] from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=32.5 ms TTL=244 jitter=0.03 ms
2021/02/15 14:22:28 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:28 : Reply[4] from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=29.9 ms TTL=244 jitter=0.28 ms
2021/02/15 14:22:29 : Reply[5] from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=27.4 ms TTL=244 jitter=0.42 ms
2021/02/15 14:22:29 : Reply[6] from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=31.3 ms TTL=244 jitter=0.63 ms
2021/02/15 14:22:30 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:31 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:31 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:32 : Reply[10] from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=33.8 ms TTL=244 jitter=0.91 ms
```

I'm only looking for lines where it doesnt reply for 2 or more times (only one timeout at a time is ok).

I've tried using awk like this, but the thing is it prints every line that matches what i want except the very last one...

```
awk -F " : " "($2 !~ /Reply/ && $2 == prev2) {print prevline} {prev2 = $2; prevline = $0} <file>
```

My question is how would you modify the awk command to print the very last line as well that consecutively matches the criteria? Or maybe a python solution? Or something with regex?

so the expected output would be

```
2021/02/15 14:22:30 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:31 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:31 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
```

since it happens on 2 or more consecutive lines, but the awk i have only prints out the first two lines and not the last (it doesnt print the time out from 14:22:28 since it happens only once, but that is expected!)

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in form of code. Could you please remove `...` from your question and add more clear samples of input and expected output for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Also please post a testable sample input file that will indicate the problem you're trying to solve. There is only one "Reply", so not clear what you want to be filtered out.

Comment: Thank you, edited the post as per requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work, perhaps can be simplified further

```
$ awk '/Reply/{c=0} c==1{print p} c; !/Reply/{c++; p=$0}' file

2021/02/15 14:22:30 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:31 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
2021/02/15 14:22:31 : 10.10.10.1: request timed out
```

keep a counter `c` to count the interested consecutive lines. Keep the copy of the first one and only print if we're still in the consecutive block (meaning `c` is not reset). Continue printing in the block.  Last statement has some redundancy since it's always keeping the previous line but doesn't have much impact.

`c;` is shorthand for `c!=0{print}`

Comment: this is the more simple solution, and it work, however could you explain what happens when you "call" c at the end of the first line?  this one -> ..} c; !/...

Comment: building on top of this and kind of merging RavinderSingh13's answer would awk '/Reply/{c=0} c==<num>{print p} c><num>{print}; !/Reply/{c++; p=(p?p ORS:"")$0} make it work with any consecutive lines? so for example every 4 or more lines?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
!/request timed out/{
  if(count>=2){ print val }
  val=""
  count=0
}
/request timed out/{
  count++
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(count>=2){ print val }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program from here.
!/request timed out/{           ##Checking condition if line is NOT having request timed out then do following.
  if(count>=2){ print val }     ##Checking condition if count is greater than equal to 2 then print val here.
  val=""                        ##Nullify val here.
  count=0                       ##Setting count to 0 here.
}
/request timed out/{            ##Checking condition if request timed out found in line then do following.
  count++                       ##Increasing count value with 1 here.
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0        ##Adding line into val and keep concatenating its value to it.
}
END{                            ##Starting END block of this code here.
  if(count>=2){ print val }     ##Checking condition if count is greater than equal to 2 then print val here.
}
'  Input_file                   ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: tried this solution, unfortunately i use awk on windows (i know, company laptop, cant have vms) and it does not run, error: val=" unterminated string (even thou i have val="" double quotes)

Comment: @blue212121, This is a successful tested code in Linux box, I don't have windows environment so can't test it there :) which version of `awk` you have?

Comment: it says GNU Awk 3.1.6

Comment: @blue212121, ideally it should work with that version or so but not sure if windows version has something different in it.

Comment: ah had to escape it with \ in cmdprompt... works like a charm now thank you!

Comment: @blue212121, your welcome cheers and happy learning :)